# Trigger being called on all rows in database

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written a trigger that I want to use for adding the date to a column in a record so that I can keep track of the insert of the item.

There are a large amount of inserts being called (about 20000) and I have noticed that the trigger will update all of the InsertDate columns associated with each item every time a new item is added. How can I make sure this happens to an item being inserted only one time.

My trigger is as follows:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_INDENTIFIER ON
 GO


 CREATE TRIGGER [InsertDate_Item]
    ON [dbo].[ItemHolder]
    AFTER INSERT
    NOT FOR REPLICATION
 AS
 UPDATE ItemHolder SET InsertDate = GETDATE()
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to restrict rows to those inserted... using the virtual trigger table INSERTED

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [InsertDate_Item]
    ON [dbo].[ItemHolder]
    AFTER INSERT
    NOT FOR REPLICATION
 AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 UPDATE IH
 SET InsertDate = GETDATE()
 FROM
    ItemHolder IH
    JOIN
    INSERTED INS ON IH.keycol = INS.keycol
 Go
```

One thing: You'd be better adding a default to the table instead. No need for a trigger

```
ALTER TABLE ItemHolder ADD
CONSTRAINT DF_ItemHolder_InsertDate DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR InsertDate
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion on better way, and fixing the original way  :) complete with sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can use the default for the insert, but I can use your answer for an LastUpdated column I plan to affiliate with each item as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

If you are inserting records into a table, why don't you make the InsertDate field have a default value of GetDate()?  That avoids the trigger altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about what you're trying to do without a trigger.  Just set the default value of the column to GetDate().

Answer (score 0):

update ih
set ih.insertdate = GetDate()
from itemholder ih inner join inserted i
on ih.itemholderid = i.itemholderid

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
UPDATE ItemHolder SET InsertDate = GETDATE()
```

to:

```
UPDATE ItemHolder SET InsertDate = GETDATE() WHERE InsertDate IS NULL
```

The above will only set InsertDate if it is null and you still want to use the trigger. Of course, this is assuming the default value of InsertDate is null. If this is not the case let me know.

Comment: There is no reason to hit every record in the table (nor query for nulls).  As gbn points out... the inserted virtual table allows update to be restriced to only those rows affected.

Comment: I did not see his post at the time of mine. I was just making a suggestion, I will refrain from offering answers unless I am sure of its merit.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange :)... where everyone's a critic :0